# Select two consecutive words by regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Since, I'm new in regular expressions; I want to make a regular expression to select two consecutive words.

For example when i give this phrase: "Hello people #RegularExpression sucks!"

It has to return these couple words:

-Hello people

-people #RegularExpression

-#RegularExpression sucks!

I tried this `/\w\s\w/i` but it did not work :(

Comment: Which regex flavour? .net, perl, javascript?

Comment: i need it for php. I guess it is perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$s = "Hello people #RegularExpression sucks!";
preg_match_all('~(?=(\S+\s+\S+))\S+\s+~', $s, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello people
    [1] => people #RegularExpression
    [2] => #RegularExpression sucks!
)
```

explanation:

`\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters.  Your `\w` was incorrect for two reasons: it only only matches one character; and it only matches a so-called *word character* (equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`).  Adding the `+` to your `\s` wasn't necessary in this test case, but there's no reason *not* to add it, and extra whitespace does have a way of sneaking into text in the real world.  (But be sure and add `+`, not `*`; there must be at least one whitespace character in there.)

`(?=...)` is a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  You use them to check whether it's *possible* to match the enclosed subexpression at the current match position, without *advancing* the match position.  Then, typically, you go ahead and match a different subexpression, not in a lookahead.

Here's the tricky bit:  Although the characters matched by the lookahead subexpression are not *consumed*, any capturing groups in the subexpression work as usual.  The lookahead in my regex, `(?=(\S+\s+\S+))` matches *and captures* the next two-word sequence.  Then (assuming the lookahead succeeded) `\S+\s+` matches in the normal way, setting the match position correctly for the next attempt.

This technique should work in any regex flavor that supports capturing groups and lookaheads.  That includes PHP as well as all the other major languages (Perl, JavaScript, .NET, Python, Java...).  The technique for accessing only the contents of the first capturing group from each match varies wildly from one language to the next, but PHP makes it easy, with `$matches[1]`.

Comment: I want to discard all of the none-alphanumeric characters exept # and @. What should I do for this?

Comment: That sounds like a separate question.  Do you want to discard them from the results (pretty easy), or not match them in the first place (not so easy)?  Do you mean to discard them from individual words, or do you want to get rid of the spaces between words, too?  [This page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) might prove helpful, if only to formulate a more useful question.

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression would actually match two letters separated by a space. So with your input you'd get `o p` and `n s`. The other issue with doing this is doing a global regular expression search on a string returns non-overlapping instances. So a proper regular expression could return `Hello people`, `#RegularExpression sucks!`, but it wouldn't return `people #RegularExpression` as that overlaps with `Hello people`. A third question is how do you define word? The classical definition, and the one used by the `\w` atom, is alphanumeric or underscore. As such, `#RegularExpression` wouldn't match because `#` isn't a word character.

In all, it sounds like what you *really* want to do is just split your string on spaces, and then you can collect all the word pairs yourself. You can do the split with something like `preg_split('/\s+/', $str)` to return an array of all whitespace-separated words, and then you can iterate over the array however you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it is *possible* to do with regex, but the pickle here is regexes consume watch they match, so "going back" to get your overlapping matches is a tricky thing to do. Regex is not the right tool for this; a hammer does not suck because it can't (properly) handle screws.

If I were you I'd just do:

```
$str =  "Hello people #RegularExpression does not suck!";
$arr = explode(' ', $str);

for ($i=0; $i<count($arr) - 1; $i++) {
    echo implode(' ', array_slice($arr, $i, 2)) . "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
Hello people
people #RegularExpression
#RegularExpression does
does not
not suck!
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, that seems not possible (**EDIT: Oops, that's wrong, see Alan's answer**) in standard pcre regex, and you better choose an another strategy.

Let me just add that it seems to exist an experimental and tricky solution : the backtracking verbs.

See the section "BACKTRACKING CONTROL" in the document [pcre.org/pcre.txt](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt)

Comment: While I can't say with certainty that backtracking-control verbs *can't* be used for this, I can say with confidence that they *shouldn't* be. ☺

Comment: Thanks for your advice and your answer, I will read more about it to understand why.

Comment: The backtracking-control verbs are intriguing, but I've never really delved into them because (1) only Perl and PCRE (similar but separate flavors) support them, and I try to focus on more widely-available features; (2) they're classed as experimental in both flavors; and (3) every time I start reading about them I'm struck by the feeling that I should be reading about parser generators or [PEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar)s instead. ☺

Answer (score -1):

This pattern should work:

```
/[^\s]+\s[^\s]+/i
```

Matches every non whitespace followed by a single whitespace char and other non whitespace chars.

Comment: `$t = 'RT @cerenkilicaslan: #kadinlardaiticiozellikler kisaca Bilkent sarisi diyoruz sacin %10luk kismi siyah,dibi ';
$a = preg_split ('/\w+\s\w+/i',$t);
print_r($a)` which returned Array
(
    [0] => RT @cerenkilicaslan: #
    [1] =>  
    [2] =>  
    [3] =>  %
    [4] =>  siyah,dibi 
)

Comment: Why preg_split?? preg_match_all('/\w+\s\w+/i', 'RT @cerenkilicaslan: #kadinlardaiticiozellikler kisaca Bilkent sarisi diyoruz sacin %10luk kismi siyah,dibi ', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER); print_r($arr); worked fine for me.

Comment: Yes it is wrong, it's late here (gmt+2) and I was to sleepy to notice I wrote something wrong. I deleted the comment as i noticed it... I am trying other solutions without preg_split but i don't get much results. Last one i tried is /\S+\s\S+/i but after it finds a couple it skips the next one. Just wondering why, maybe I should open a new question about that... O_o

Comment: Regex consumes what it matches. To get overlapping matches you'd have to get the regex engine to "go back." I think you might get it to work  if you use lookaround, but I haven't had any success with that.