# two consecutive words regular expression on PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm new in regular expressions; I want to make a regular expression to select two consecutive words.I found a related topic but I didn't get right answers from that.

For example, Here is a phrase: Color Image Processing with ;

**It has to return these couple words:**

Color Image

Image Processing

Processing with

I used `/\w{1,}\s\w{1,}/`, but it returns:

Color image

processing with;

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250764/select-two-consecutive-words-by-regular-expression?rq=1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [Positive Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) here.

```
preg_match_all('/(?=([a-z]+\s+[a-z]+))[a-z]+/i', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Color Image
    [1] => Image Processing
    [2] => Processing with
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "Color Image Processing with ;";
$wordPairs = array();
preg_match_all('~\w+~',$string,$words);
foreach ($words[0] as $i => $word) {
  if (isset($words[0][$i+1]))
    $wordPairs[] = $word . ' ' . $words[0][$i+1];
}

print_r($wordPairs);

/* output */
Array
(
    [0] => Color Image
    [1] => Image Processing
    [2] => Processing with
)
```

Comment: thank you!! It also a great approach!